# Intensity due to linear superposition of two electric field (of linearly polarised light)

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

Let

$\vec{E_{1}} = \hat{e_{1}}|\vec{E}_{1}| e^{i(\vec{k}\vec{r} - \omega t)}e^{i\phi_{1}}$

and

$\vec{E_{2}} = \hat{e_{2}}|\vec{E}_{2}| e^{i(\vec{k}\vec{r} - \omega t)}e^{i\phi_{2}}$

be the electric field of two linearly polarised light.

Because of the linear superposition principle, the vector addition of $\vec{E_{1}}$ and $\vec{E_{2}}$ can be added to yield a resultant electric field, $\vec{E}$.

If we take the square of the magnitude of $\vec{E}$, we get the intensity of $\vec{E}$.

using the inner product, the calculation works out to be

$\begin{align}
|E|^2&=\langle E_1+E_2, E_1+E_2 \rangle=\langle E_1, E_1+E_2 \rangle +\langle E_2, E_1+E_2 \rangle\\
&=\langle E_1, E_1 \rangle+\langle E_1, E_2 \rangle +\langle E_2, E_1 \rangle +\langle E_2, E_2 \rangle\\
&=|E_1|^2 + |E_2|^2+2\langle E_1, E_2 \rangle\\
&=|E_1|^2 + |E_2|^2+2|E_1| |E_2| \cos(\phi)
\end{align}$

In the last term of the last line, what is the physical significance of $\vec{E_{1}}$ projected onto $\vec{E_{2}}$ with an relative phase difference $\phi = \phi_{2} - \phi_{1}$  to the intensity of $\vec{E}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last term there represents *interference* between the plane waves.  You correctly add the amplitudes of the fields.  The fields oscillate between negative and positive values at the frequency of the waves.  But the waves can be out of phase by, for example, $\pi$ radians in which case the cosine factor becomes a minus sign.

Consider the case in which $E_1 = E_2$ and $\phi = \pi$.   Curiously, the total intensity is zero.  This is interference.  In fact, the total amplitude is zero everywhere at all times. How is that possible?  The issue here is that a plane wave is non-physical.  A plane wave has infinite extent, and it's just not possible to produce such a thing.  Physics has nothing to say about non-physical situations.  But we can get a glimpse of what really happens by having the two waves have different $\vec{k}$ vectors (but the same frequency).   In this case the interference varies from point to point, in some places subtracting to get zero, in other places adding, doubling the field strength, and at still other places taking every value in between.

**addendum**

I just noticed that the polarization vectors of your two waves is different ($\hat{e}_2$ and $\hat{e}_2$).   What I wrote above applies only if the polarization vectors are the same.  When they are different, as they are in this case, there is no destructive interference.  If the two polarization vectors are perpendicular to each other, then $\left<E_1,E_2\right>=0$ and the third term in your final expression vanishes.  Furthermore, care must be taken to add the fields vectorially.  In the case where   $E_1 = E_2$ and $\phi = \pi$, adding the fields results in *circular polarization*.

Comment: In other words, in your given example, the event is a destructive interference.

Is there a link to where I can read more on the "total amplitude is zero everywhere at all times"?

Comment: I don't know of any place where that is explicitly discussed.  If you want to work it out yourself, make the two polarization vectors the same, and to make life a little easier set the phase of $E_1$ to unity, and the phase of $E_2$ to be $\exp{(i\phi)}$.  Doing so adds no additional restriction; it just puts all of the phase shift in wave $2$.   Now set $E_1 = E_2$ and $\phi = \pi$ in your original expressions and see what happens.